# Windows API Combobox data not being inserted

Tags: c++, windows, api, combobox

I'm trying to assign an int to each item in a ComboBox.

Here's my code:

```
int itemIndex = ComboBox_InsertString(hComboBox, -1, strData);
if (itemIndex > -1)
{
    // idataIndex is always 0
    // and ComboBox_GetItemData() always returns 0 regardless of what intData is
    int idataIndex = ComboBox_InsertItemData(hComboBox, itemIndex, intData);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? This seems pretty straightforward.

**EDIT:**
Figured it out, `ComboBox_InsertItemData` sends `CB_INSERTSTRING` instead of `CB_SETITEMDATA`. I needed to send `CB_SETITEMDATA` to set the item data.

Comment: How is intData declared and set?

Comment: @Chris `int intData = 20;`, and I've checked it in a debugger, and intData is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use [ComboBox_SetItemData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb856486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead? This macro sends the CB_SETITEMDATA